# nested foreach() iteration is mixing up target collections

Tags: c#, foreach, nested, iteration

I'm trying to write a script in space-engineers, and I have a collection of a class `_Filter`, which resides inside of another class `_Inventory`. Here is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```cs
public void InventorySetup(_Inventory inventory)
{

    if (inventory.InvBlock != null)                                                                             // Check if block exists
    {
        string[] data = inventory.InvBlock.CustomData.Split('\n');                                              // Break customData into lines

        foreach (string nextline in data)                                                                       // Iterate each line
        {
            if (nextline.Length > 0)                                                                            // Line must contain information
            {
                string[] lineblocks = nextline.Split(' ');                                                      // Break each line into blocks

                if (lineblocks.Length > 1)                                                                      // There must be more than one block to have filter candidate and desired update
                {
                    string[] itemID = new string[2];

                    if (lineblocks[0].Contains(":"))
                        itemID = lineblocks[0].Split(':');                                                      // split the type from subType


                    else if (lineblocks[0].Contains("!"))
                        itemID = new string[] { "", "" };

                    else
                        itemID = new string[] { "null", "null" };

                    foreach (_Filter nextFilter in inventory.Filters)
                    {
                        if (ContainsCIS(nextFilter.ItemType, itemID[0]) && ContainsCIS(nextFilter.ItemSubType, itemID[1]))
                        {
                            for (int i = 1; i < lineblocks.Length; i++)
                            {
                                switch (lineblocks[i][0])
                                {
                                    case '#':
                                        nextFilter.Target = (MyFixedPoint)float.Parse(lineblocks[i].Replace('#', ' '));

                                        break;

                                    case '+':
                                        if (ContainsCIS(lineblocks[i], "in"))
                                            nextFilter.IN_BOUND = true;
                                        if (ContainsCIS(lineblocks[i], "out"))
                                            nextFilter.OUT_BOUND = true;
                                        break;

                                    case '-':
                                        if (ContainsCIS(lineblocks[i], "in"))
                                            //                                                    nextFilter.IN_BOUND = false;

                                            if (ContainsCIS(lineblocks[i], "out"))
                                                nextFilter.OUT_BOUND = false;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (nextline[0] == '&')
                {
                    if (ContainsCIS(nextline, "empty"))
                    {
                        if (nextline.Contains("-"))
                            inventory.EMPTY = false;
                        else
                            inventory.EMPTY = true;
                    }
                    if (ContainsCIS(nextline, "fill"))
                    {
                        if (nextline.Contains("-"))
                            inventory.FILL = false;
                        else
                            inventory.FILL = true;
                    }
                    if (ContainsCIS(nextline, "active"))
                    {
                        if (nextline.Contains("-"))
                            inventory.ACTIVE = false;
                        else
                            inventory.ACTIVE = true;
                    }
                    if (ContainsCIS(nextline, "clean"))
                    {
                        if (nextline.Contains("-"))
                            inventory.CLEAN = false;
                        else
                            inventory.CLEAN = true;
                    }

                    if (ContainsCIS(nextline, "reset"))
                        inventory.Reset();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically what's going on, there's a member within the `_Inventory` class that refers directly to the block who's inventory I'm trying to configure. This member has it's own member called `CustomData`, which is a string object that can be edited in game. So I split it into an array of each line, and then process each line based on the contextual nature of each.

First, the line gets broken up into "blocks" by once again splitting each line by a space character, and then analyzing further. If the number of blocks is greater than `1`, this means there is an expected "target filter" and some sort of following qualifier. Either a change to its white-list/black-list setting, or a change to the target maximum value (0 means no limit and is the default value for this member).

Now the `_Inventory` class already contains a pre-existing collection of `_Filter` class, and merely updates the members of it by means of iteration. So for example, if I want to black-list "IN_BOUND" ores, I would add the line "ore: -in". or if I want to black-list out bound steel plates, ":steelplate -out".
(a name before the colon depicts the category, and one after the colon, the specific type of item. Exclamation mark means all items in the collection). The `ContainCIS()` method is something I made simply to search for a contained string "Case In-Sensitively". Besides changing filters, the `_Inventory` class also possesses a few bool members for controlling desired functionality. They are self-named `EMPTY`, `FILL`, `ACTIVE`, `CLEAN` (the clean bool has to do with production blocks that sometimes get stuffed with the wrong materials, non-relevant to my problem)

**My actual problem:**
When this code is called, if I only have a single `_Inventory` in the root collection, everything works out fine. HOWEVER, if I have more than one, the bools are updated normally, but the filters GET UPDATED IN REVERSE ORDER.

So say for example I have `_Inventory A`, and `_Inventory B`. If I add the line to the custom data of the block that is referred to by "A", then the correct bool changes. But if I change a filter setting on "A", it updates to "B" instead.

EDIT:
Here's the classes and the method which calls the InventorySetup():

```
    public class _Inventory
    {
        public IMyTerminalBlock InvBlock;
        public _BlockType BlockType;        // Cargo, Assembler, Refinery
        public _Filter[] Filters;           // Expected inventory candidates (Refer to _Filter libraries)
        public bool FILL;                   // Attempt fill action on all IN_BOUND "true" candidates
        public bool EMPTY;                  // Attempt empty action on all OUT_BOUND "true" candidates
        public bool ACTIVE;                 // Actively being manipulated by program ("Use conveyor system" property will be disabled on prod. blocks)
        public bool CLEAN;                  // Actively clear overburdened assembler inputs, or un-scheduled refinery inputs (not used for cargos)

        public _Inventory(IMyTerminalBlock invBlock, _BlockType blockType, _Filter[] filters, bool active = true)
        {
            InvBlock = invBlock;
            BlockType = blockType;
            Filters = filters;
            FILL = false;
            EMPTY = false;
            ACTIVE = active;
            CLEAN = true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            foreach (_Filter nextFilter in Filters)
            {
                nextFilter.Target = 0;
                nextFilter.IN_BOUND = true;
                nextFilter.OUT_BOUND = true;
            }
        }
    }

public class _Filter
    {
        public string ItemType;
        public string ItemSubType;

        public MyFixedPoint Target;
        public int Priority;

        public bool IN_BOUND;
        public bool OUT_BOUND;

        public _Filter(string itemType = "null")
        {
            ItemType = itemType.Split(':')[0];
            ItemSubType = itemType.Split(':')[1];
            Target = 0;                     // 0 means no target value, any amount aloud
            Priority = 0;                   // Priority for in-bound requests (WIP)
            IN_BOUND = true;                // Default to whitelist items in & out of inventory
            OUT_BOUND = true;
        }
    }

public void InventoryListUpdate()
    {
        Inventories.RemoveAll(x => x.InvBlock == null);
        Inventories.RemoveAll(x => !x.InvBlock.CustomName.Contains(Signature));

        foreach (IMyCargoContainer nextCargo in Cargos)
        {
            if (Inventories.FindIndex(x => x.InvBlock == nextCargo) < 0 && nextCargo.CustomName.Contains(Signature))
                Inventories.Add(new _Inventory((IMyTerminalBlock)nextCargo, _BlockType.CARGO, FullLibrary));
        }
        foreach (IMyRefinery nextRefinery in Refineries)
        {
            if (Inventories.FindIndex(x => x.InvBlock == nextRefinery) < 0 && nextRefinery.CustomName.Contains(Signature))
                Inventories.Add(new _Inventory((IMyTerminalBlock)nextRefinery, _BlockType.ASSEMBLER, RefineryLibrary));
        }
        foreach (IMyAssembler nextAssembler in Assemblers)
        {
            if (Inventories.FindIndex(x => x.InvBlock == nextAssembler) < 0 && nextAssembler.CustomName.Contains(Signature))
                Inventories.Add(new _Inventory((IMyTerminalBlock)nextAssembler, _BlockType.ASSEMBLER, AssembleLibrary, false));
        }

        foreach (_Inventory nextInventory in Inventories)
        {
            if (bInventoryRunning && nextInventory.ACTIVE)
                InventoryUpdate(nextInventory);
            else
                InventorySetup(nextInventory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you see a indention of the length "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" something is wrong

Comment: @Klamsi, Ya I know it looks terrible, thankyou for the tangent on code etiquette xD. I do plan on re-factoring, I just wanna make sure it does what it's supposed to before I bother prettying it up.

Comment: I believe if you try to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you will end up a more readable question.

Comment: @lastr2d2, thats actually a good idea, I will try to re-create this as consicely as I can

Comment: @ClarkThomson: I would go the other direction. First clean up, then search for the error. Searching is much easier and, as mentioned, creating a minimal example is easier.

Comment: Agree. For example, in a loop use `if(nextline.Length==0)continue;` rather than >0 and having to indent the whole loop block.. i.e. "if the condition is bad, skip the loop" rather than "if the condition is good, do all this stuff"

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug if we could see the class definitions for inventory and filter, and we had an example data input file.

Comment: @Tim, it should only over-write if it matches the "ID" qualifier, and the next block actually contains a "+" or a "-". This is intended so that multiple filters can be updated simultaneously with a single line if there is a similar keyword within their filter ID's

Comment: @Caius Jard, I didn't know about the continue keyword, thankyou! I'll try that out

Comment: Sample input file?

Comment: @Caius Jard, do you mean like a sample of the CustomData? or a sample of the IMyTerminalBlock?

Answer (score 0):

So when I started up the code in space engineers today, it suddenly started to work as intended... I have absolutely no idea how or why. I'm leaning towards a memory leak issue related to how the game handles its in-game scripts, however there is the slight possibility that cleaning the code up somehow "massaged" it to do as intended. As I stated before, it was behaving as expected to some degree, it just had un-expected behaviour as the higher collection grew in size. Since each _Inventory was being worked on individually, there should have been no way for its members to get transposed onto another, unless some weird GC-voodoo was happening in the background. As comforting as it is to have my script running properly, it's an even worse feeling knowing I may never find out why it was messing up in the first place, as I have no real solid grounding from which to avoid this problem in the future. Thankyou all for your input.

Comment: We have the before code; Show the after code, and a sample input file that causes the before code to fail and the after code to work

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been awhile since I posted this, but I feel like I have a responsibility to bring further conclusions to the issue I was having. I only just realized that the problem revolved around a particular class array that I had added to the container class. The _Filter[] within _Inventory, had been passed by reference, rather than being "cloned", something I have just recently become aware of, so every time each individual _Inventory object was being iterated through, their contained arrays were all pointing to the same thing. I have managed to find a way to properly clone each element from the original libraries as needed.